# Extracting nodes path inside an xml using xquery in correct order

Tags: t-sql, path, extract, nodes, xquery

I'm using TSQL but I'm not an expert, so I copied and adapted a query found on this site.
I have tried to extract the list of all the nodes (included their path) inside an xml file, that I assigned to a variable.

The query works, but it returns the second level nodes with their children "Customer1", "Customer2" in reverse order.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @xml xml =
N'<General>
  <Customer1>
    <model_year1>2011</model_year1>
    <vehicle_id>1</vehicle_id>
    <mileage>34000</mileage>
  </Customer1>
  <Customer2>
    <model_year1>2012</model_year1>
    <vehicle_id>2</vehicle_id>
    <mileage>35000</mileage>
  </Customer2>
</General>';
-----------------
WITH Xml_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
       CAST('/' + node.value('fn:local-name(.)',
           'varchar(100)') AS varchar(100)) AS nodes_name,
       node.query('*') AS children
    FROM @xml.nodes('/*') AS roots(node)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CAST(x.nodes_name + '/' + 
            node.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') AS varchar(100)),
        node.query('*') AS children
    FROM Xml_CTE x
    CROSS APPLY x.children.nodes('*') AS child(node)
)
SELECT nodes_name
FROM Xml_CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```

This is the result:

1/General

2/General/Customer1

3/General/Customer2

4/General/Customer2/model_year1

5/General/Customer2/vehicle_id

6/General/Customer2/mileage

7/General/Customer1/model_year1

8/General/Customer1/vehicle_id

9/General/Customer1/mileage

But I expected:

1/General

2/General/Customer1

3/General/Customer2

4/General/Customer1/model_year1

5/General/Customer1/vehicle_id

6/General/Customer1/mileage

7/General/Customer2/model_year1

8/General/Customer2/vehicle_id

9/General/Customer2/mileage

---

My question is: why I got

General/Customer2/model_year1

General/Customer2/vehicle_id

General/Customer2/mileage

before

General/Customer1/model_year1

General/Customer1/vehicle_id

General/Customer1/mileage

Comment: I am a little bit lost here : does your expected result contain the 1/ 2/ ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the  node appears before the  node, so the query in reality is processing the children of  before moving on to the children of . That's why you see the child nodes of  appearing before the child nodes of  in the result set.

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'
<General>
  <Customer1>
    <model_year1>2011</model_year1>
    <vehicle_id>1</vehicle_id>
    <mileage>34000</mileage>
  </Customer1>
  <Customer2>
    <model_year1>2012</model_year1>
    <vehicle_id>2</vehicle_id>
    <mileage>35000</mileage>
  </Customer2>
</General>';

WITH Xml_CTE AS
(SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [Index],
  'General' AS [Path]
FROM @xml.nodes('/General') AS XT1(X1)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [Index],
  'General/' + CustomerNode.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') AS [Path]
FROM @xml.nodes('/General/*') AS XT2(X2)
CROSS APPLY XT2.X2.nodes('.') AS XT3(CustomerNode)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [Index],
  'General/' + XT4.CustomerNode.value('local-name(..)', 'varchar(100)') + '/' +
  XT4.CustomerNode.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') AS [Path]
FROM @xml.nodes('/General/*/*') AS XT4(CustomerNode))

SELECT Path
FROM Xml_CTE
```

| Path |
| --- |
| General |
| General/Customer1 |
| General/Customer2 |
| General/Customer1/model_year1 |
| General/Customer1/vehicle_id |
| General/Customer1/mileage |
| General/Customer2/model_year1 |
| General/Customer2/vehicle_id |
| General/Customer2/mileage |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wltz7HYg)